# Ruby RoR parsing a string upper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parsing

I'm new to ruby, I would like to parse each char from this string for example `str = "Amdh#34HB!x"` and get the result like this :

1) into string

```
"Upper : 3 Lower : 4 numbers : 2 special : 2"
```

2)  stock results into variables

```
@Upper = 3
@Lower = 4
@numbers = 2
@special = 2
```

Any help please ?

Comment: we can create those variables just after getting the string results by parsing it as well I think, right?

Comment: do you want to consider `<space>` as special character in string ?, ideally you should not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = 'Amdh#34HB!x'

upper = s.scan(/[A-Z]/).count
lower = s.scan(/[a-z]/).count
numbers = s.scan(/[0-9]/).count
special = s.scan(/[^a-z0-9]/i).count

"Upper: #{upper} Lower: #{lower} Numbers: #{numbers} Special: #{special}"

#=> "Upper: 3 Lower: 4 Numbers: 2 Special: 2"
```

Comment: Great !!  it works, thank you very much but can you explain what this does exactly `special = s.scan(/[^a-z0-9]/i).count` and the `/i` so I can understand better

Comment: Happy to help! The trailing `i` makes the regex case insensitive, so it's a shorter way of writing `/[^A-Za-z0-9]/`. The `^` means **not** matching the following characters.

Comment: Making separate scan and counts for each character type is relatively inefficient, which could be a concern if the string `s` is extremely long.

Answer (score 2):

there are many ways to do this, the most didatic in my opinion is

```
str = gets.chomp # Here you get the string from user
@Upper = 0
@Lower = 0
@numbers = 0
@special = 0
for char in str.chars do
    if /[a-z]/=~ char then
        @Lower += 1
    elsif /[A-Z]/=~ char then
        @Upper += 1
    elsif /[0-9]/=~ char then
        @numbers += 1
    else
        @special += 1
    end
end
puts "Upper : #{@Upper} Lower : #{@Lower} numbers : #{@numbers} special : #{@special}"
```

Comment: Using `for` in ruby is considered a really bad practice. You should change to `str.chars.each do |char|`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but when I tested this (I replaced str by the example above)  I got as result  `Upper : 0 Lower : 10 numbers : 0 special : 0`

Comment: sorry, i forgot some "|" in the regex

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to obtain the counts by making a single pass through the string, regardless of the number of character categories.

**Code**

```
CATS = { upper: /[[:upper:]]/, lower: /[[:lower:]]/,
         number: /[[:digit:]]/, special: /./ }

def count_character_types(str)
  str.each_char.with_object(CATS.keys.product([0]).to_h) do |c,h|
    k,_ = CATS.find { |k,r| c =~ r } 
    h[k] += 1
  end
end
```

**Example**

```
h = count_character_types("Amdh#34HB!x")
  #=> {:upper=>3, :lower=>4, :number=>2, :special=>2}
```

Note that

```
CATS.keys.product([0]).to_h
  #=> {:upper=>0, :lower=>0, :number=>0, :special=>0}
```

**Convert hash to a string**

A hash may be a more useful return value than a string, but if you want a string, there's one more step:

```
h.map { |k,v| "#{k.to_s.capitalize} : #{v}" }.join(' ')
  #=> "Upper : 3 Lower : 2 Number : 2 : 4 Special"
```

`"Digit"` would be a more accurate name for the key `"Number"`.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help and suggestion!! Could you please  explain more to understand better what the code does exactely.

Comment: I know it's the declaration of the hash but what `upper: /[[:upper:]]/` and `special: /./` means?  and what if I want to add the length of that `str` into the hash ?

Comment: `[[:..:]]` are *POSIX bracket expressions*. See the doc for [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html) and search for "POSIX". `/[[:upper:]]/`, `/[[:lower:]]/` and `/[[:digit:]]` are similar to the following regexes containing a single character class: `/[A-Z]/`, `/[a-z]/` and `/[0-9]/', except the former support unicode characters, such as accented letters. You could alternatively use \p{} constructs (search on that in the same doc). The regex `/./` matches any character (other than a newline), so `c =~ /./` will always return `0` (truthy) if find gets that far (cont...).

Comment: ...If you are only concerned about supporting ASCII, by all means use `/[A-Z]/`, `/[a-z]/` and `/[0-9]/`. If, however, you need to support unicode in future, someone may have to modify those ASCII-oriented regexes. For that reason, many Ruby coders now used POSIX or `\p{}` expressions exclusively.